# expected value of two multiplying random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

I have two random variables, say $X$ and $Y$ which are not correlated. 
then $$|E[XY]|$$is
greater, equal or less than $$E[|XY|]?$$

Answer (score 1):

Jensen's inequality states that for any integrable random variable $Z$ the inequality $|E[Z]| \le E[|Z|]$ holds.

Comment: If x and y are complex no then what we can say....Dominik

Comment: The same inequality also holds for complex random variables, since the map $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a norm and therefore convex.